# Why $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Why $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ . Can anyone explain ? Thanks

Comment: To be a subspace requires being a *subset*.  While we often consider $\mathbb R^2$ to be "the $xy$-plane" sitting inside the $xyz$-space $\mathbb R^3$, there are actually an infinite number of two-dimensional subspaces of any three-dimensional space, so the picture of one "sitting inside" another requires a convention to settle on one particular inclusion.

Answer (score 5):

It's because an Element in $\mathbb R^2$ has the form $(a,b)$ while one in $\mathbb R^3$ has the form $(x,y,z)$, so $"(a,b) \neq (x,y,z)"$ for any choices of $a,b,x,y,z$. So you cannot say that $\mathbb R^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$.

But perhaps you want to look at $\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ versus $\mathbb R^3$? You can check the axioms here.

The thing is basically that $\mathbb R^2$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ while $\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$ is. But what might result in some confusion is that $\mathbb R^2$ is obviously isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2 \times \{0\}$.

Comment: an element in $R^2 \times \{ 0 \} $ is just $(x,y,0)$ . correct?

Comment: Exactly, the last coordinate is always $0$ since there is no other element in $\{0\}$.